# When hover on button1 show button2

Tags: css, hover

I try to use a CSS-Solution to show other buttons when hover a special button.

The HTML-code is this.

```
<div class="button-group">
  <button type="button" name="add_wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart "></i></button>
  <button type="button" name="add_cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart "></i></button>
  <button type="button" name="add_compare"><i class="fa fa-exchange "></i></button>
</div>
```

The CSS-code looks like this:

```
.button-group button {
    color              : #999;
    font-family        : 'FontAwesome';
    font-size          : 1rem;
    font-weight        : normal;
    margin             : 0;
    padding            : .500rem 0.875rem;
    background         : #fff;
    display            : inline-block;
    transition         : all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition    : all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition : all 0.3s linear;
    opacity            : 0;
}

.button-group button[name="add_cart"] {
  opacity : 1;  
}
```

My idea with

```
.button-group button[name="add_cart"]:hover + .button-group button[name="add_compare"] {
  opacity : 1;
}
```

doesn't work.

How the CSS should look like to show the two other buttons on hover the button "add_cart"?

Comment: You can't refer upwards/backwards in the DOM with CSS.

Comment: On this page http://fabiademo6.magikcommerce.com/index.php?route=common/home ist works but I can't sort out the referring CSS

Comment: It's probably done with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this only for the third button "add_compare" as it is "after" the "add_cart" button using something like this (assuming you give them ID add_cart and add_compare):

```
 #add_cart:hover + #add_compare {
           opacity:1;
    }
```

But for first button it can't be done using pure CSS as far as I know. You would need to use Javascript for that.